# Make secondary modeless windows visible when main window activated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winforms application with a main form that creates multiple secondary notification windows. These secondary windows do NOT have an owner and are modeless, because I want the main form to be able to be on top of them. They also are not shown in the taskbar (ShownInTaskbar = False).

Now, if the main window is minimized (or another application is put on top of it), and I click my application's icon in the taskbar, I want all of the secondary windows to be shown as well (but with the main window on top of them if they overlap).  So, I want my main window on the very top, the secondary windows behind it, and any other applications behind THEM.

To accomplish this, I keep a list of these secondary windows in memory. I wrote the following event handler to show the secondary windows:

```
private void SmgWfMainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(SecondaryWindow sw in _secondaryWindows)
    {
        sw.BringToFront();
    }
    this.BringToFront();
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. What happens is that the final call to this.BringToFront() causes the Activated event handler to fire again, and the handler keeps starting over and over again in an endless loop. I am never able to interact with my main form because of this. If I leave out that call, the last secondary window gets focus, and if I click on my main form, the event fires and the secondary windows are again on top of the main form and I have the same issue.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Is there something else that I can call besides this.BringToFront() that will not cause the Activated event to fire again?  Or maybe another event that I can listen on that won't get triggered by this.BringToFront()?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean variable to prevent reentrance:

```
private bool _activatingFromEvent = false;

protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs evt)
{
  if(_activatingFromEvent)
  {
    // Don't call the event this time
    _activatingFromEvent = false;
    return;
  }
  base.OnActivated(evt);
}

private void SmgWfMainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_activatingFromEvent) 
      return;
    _activatingFromEvent = true;
    foreach(SecondaryWindow sw in _secondaryWindows)
    {
        sw.BringToFront();
    }
    this.BringToFront();
}
```

This would solve your immediate problem without changing too much code.

---

***Edit***: I see now you say your forms are not owned, so I guess they were not for a reason, so disregard the rest of the answer. I'll leave it here anyway

Another way to do what you want, is having your secondary forms be"owned" by your main form (when you show them, pass in your main form to the `Show` method [using this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx), or set the [`Owner` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner)).

This has more implications though, so be wary if you want them:

1. If you close your main form, the owned forms will close too
2. An owned form will always display over the owner form
3. When your owner form minimizes, all its owned forms get hidden (and they show again when it gets restored)

If that works for you, you'd be better off having owned forms

Comment: Jcl, thanks. I tried what you wrote, and it did not work as-is. This is because the this.BringToFront() call triggers the Activated event, which has a slight delay before the reentrance occurs, and therefore _activatingFromEvent is set to false BEFORE the reentrance happens. I got it to work by calling Application.DoEvents() after this.BringToFront(). However I know that Application.DoEvents() is generally frowned upon. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Oh, by the way, in #2 of your answer about the "owner" property, I think you meant to say, "An OWNER form can never display over the OWNED form", correct? This is indeed the reason that I made the secondary forms ownerless.

Comment: Yes. I meant that. Sorry, I'm on my phone right now. Will make some tests when I'm at my home pc and let you know about possible solutions

Comment: @JoeMjr2 I see the problem, `BringToFront` probably requests the activation but the `WM_ACTIVATE` message is not send till afterwards, I'll edit and add an alternative

Comment: @JoeMjr2 I've made an edit where you override `OnActivate` and just don't call the event the first time it's sent after the last one. This should do as long as `Activated` is only raised once after `BringToFront` (it should, but you should test it). While I don't frown upon `DoEvents()` ***if*** used correctly (and understanding the implications), using it during an event handler is not wise, since it'll consume the message queue and call all the events for pending messages while your handler is not even finished yet